# Converting tsv with arrays to JSON with jq

Tags: arrays, json, bash, csv, jq

i found [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/) very helpful in converting tsv to JSON file, however, i want to figure out how to do it with jq when i have array in my tsv:

```
name    age    pets
Tim    15    cats,dogs
Joe    11    rabbits,birds
...
```

ideal JSON:

```
[
 {
  name: "Tim",
  age: "15",
  pet:["cats","dogs"]
 },
  name: "Joe",
  age: "11",
  pet:["rabbits","birds"]
 }, ...
]
```

This is the command i tried:

```
cat file.tsv | jq -s  --slurp --raw-input --raw-output 'split("\n") | .[1:-1] | map(split("\t")) |
        map({"name": .[0],
             "age": .[1],
             "pet": .[2]})'
```

and the output the the above command is:

```
[
 {
  name: "Tim",
  age: "15",
  pet:"cats,dogs"
 },
  name: "Joe",
  age: "11",
  pet:"rabbits,birds"-
 }, ...
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case the name includes any commas, I'd go with the following, which also avoids having to "slurp" the input:

```
inputs
| split("\t")
| {name: .[0], age: .[1], pet: .[2]}
| .pet |= split(",")
```

To skip the header, simply invoke jq with the -R option, e.g. like this:

```
jq -R -f program.jq input.tsv
```

If you want the result as an array, simply enclose the entire filter above in square brackets.

Comment: thank you for yr answer, you are right, i prefer changing only certain columns to array. It's nice to learn about .jq too!

Comment: however, there seems to be two small problems: missing comma between each {}, and missing outter [], which can be fixed by piping the jq to sed 's/}/},/g;1s/^/[/;$s/,$/]/', i wonder if i can solve it inside jq?

Comment: Yes, you can achieve it in jq, as mentioned in the @peak 's answer you need to put the **whole** jq filter statement in the brackets.

Answer (score 7):

Like this:

```
jq -rRs 'split("\n")[1:-1] |
         map([split("\t")[]|split(",")] | {
                 "name":.[0],
                 "age":.[1],
                 "pet":.[2]
             }
    )' input.tsv
```